# QGIS temp shapefile missing

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am creating a buffer around a PDA point.  Something I have done previously with no problems.  However, this time it is coming up with an error message saying, it has failed to open the Shapefile 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 2,18\bin\temp.shp'.

I've looked into that location and there is no temp shapefile.  Any idea where I can get/re-create one?

Comment: Did you get the error during the buffer creation or when you try to reopen your project ?

Comment: when I tried to create the buffer.  I've shut down and re-opened QGIS, no warning came up.

Comment: Temporary data gets deleted whenever you close QGIS. So your point, if not made permanent, is gone for good.

Comment: my point is permanent and that is what I am trying to create a buffer from.  just odd no temp file

Comment: What's your aim ? is recreating the buffer a problem ? which tool or algorithm do u use to create the buffer ?

Comment: @Rebecca - Does it work if you save the buffer as a shapefile?

Comment: I don't know if it was the tool or you who had done it but writing data to the bin directory is asking for trouble. If it was you then don't! You might end up corrupting the core libraries of QGIS...